# System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload issues with "AllowMultiple" and "PostedFiles" during Multiple FileUpload Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

So I'm trying to upload multiple files (images) in asp.net 4.0. I have done this before and just a little time ago this was working and all I did was try to debug a value and after that it started crying.

I have tried googling (in case you wonder) but I can't find the solution to my problem.

So here's the **aspx** code

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" Multiple="Multiple" runat="server" />
```

I changed the `AllowMultiple="true"` to `Multiple="Multiple"` after knowing the former is for asp.net 4.5 and above and that's weird because it worked before.

This is my **.cs** code.

```
foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../Pics/" + filename));

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into slider(photo) values(@ImagePath)", conn);


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", filename);

                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();



            }
```

It gives a blue underline on PostedFiles and the error reads

`"'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload' does not contain a definition for 'PostedFiles' and no extension method 'PostedFiles' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`

And another error also appears:

`"'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload' does not contain a definition for 'AllowMultiple' and no extension method 'AllowMultiple' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"`

And after changing it to `Multiple="Multiple"` I'm getting this following warning:

`Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'Multiple' is not a valid attribute of element 'FileUpload'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so, after searching and searching I did find the answer to my issue. And that is

asp.net 4.0 does not allow multiple upload somehow. I'll have to use some plugin  or something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

 if (fuPhoto.HasFiles)
            {
                PicsCount = fuPhoto.PostedFiles.Count;
            }
```

this will not work.
change the targetFramwork like

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
```

it will work perfectly.